How to resolve The ReferenceToken type doesn't accept collections as value when executing CreateAnalyticsModules?
I want to send analytics from the security device to the HIK Vision live view via API requests, which is via CreateAnalyticsModules. My device model is DS-2CD1023G0E-I(L) with firmware version V5.7.2 build 220111. But when I run my code, I keep getting Unknown error: The ReferenceToken type doesn't accept collections as value. I tried many ways and still face the same error. Please help I've been stuck for days and ChatGPT can't help me anymore :')
I attempted to create this function:
Create analytics service
# Connect to the camera
mycam = ONVIFCamera(camera_ip, port, username, password)

def create_analytics_configuration(mycam, profile_token):
    try:
        analytics_service = mycam.create_analytics_service()
    
            # Create a new analytics configuration
            analytics_config = analytics_service.create_type('CreateAnalyticsModules')
            analytics_config.ConfigurationToken = profile_token
            analytics_config.AnalyticsEngineConfiguration = {
                'AnalyticsModule': [{
                    'Name': 'TextOverlay',
                    'Type': 'TextOverlay',
                    'Parameters': {
                        'Parameter': [
                            {'Name': 'TextString', 'Value': 'Example Annotation'},
                            {'Name': 'Position', 'Value': 'top-left'}
                        ] 
                    }
                }]
            }
            print(f"Step 2: New analytics_config: {analytics_config}   # used to create      Analytics-Modules\n")
    
            # Create the analytics modules using the configuration
            analytics_service.CreateAnalyticsModules(analytics_config)
         
            print("New Video Analytics Configuration created successfully.")
except ONVIFError as e:
    print(f"Error creating analytics configuration: {e}")

Getting profiles
profiles = media_service.GetProfiles()
profile_token = profiles\[0\].token
print(type(profile_token)) # Output: \<class 'str'\>

create the service
create_analytics_configuration(mycam, profile_token)

